# write an algorithm to find the maximum value

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Example:
numbers are [1, 2, 3] and u have +, *
max value is 1+2*3

example [1, 1, 1] , ans is 1+1+1

I can think of a simple recursive algorithm:

```
private static double helper(double[] arr, int s, int e) {
   System.out.println("s= " + s + " e= " + e);
   //base case:  if single elem, return that eleme
   if (e==s) {
      return arr[s];
    } if (s+1==e) {
        return Math.max(arr[s]+arr[e], arr[s]*arr[e]);
      } else if (s>e) {
      //this should never happen
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("invalid operation");
   }

   //int mid = s+ ((e-s)/2);
   int mid=s;
    double fMax = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   for (mid=s;mid<e;mid++) {
     //divide and conqr route
     double lres = helperDQ(arr,s, mid);
     double  rres = helperDQ(arr,mid+1, e );
     System.out.println("s= " + s + " e = " + e + " m = " + mid + " lres= " + lres + " rres= " + rres);
     fMax = Math.max(fMax, Math.max(lres*rres, lres+rres));
    }
    return fMax;  
} 

private static double findMax(double[] arr) {
        return helper(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
}
```

Is there a better way to do instead of this recursive way? We can prune the recursion by checking for s, e so we dont end up recursing same thing multiple times.

Can't think of an easy dynamic programming approach way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 0 and 1 should always be added, any other value should be multiplied.  You want to add 1 to the smallest number available.

Comment: It can be easily done using variant of chain matrix multiplication and i guess it has been answered on SO before many times

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be solved a lot easier, using some simple math. For any two numbers `a` and `b`, the following applies: unless either `a = 1` or `b = 1` is given, `a * b >= a + b` is given (assuming `a >= 1` and `b >= 1`). This applies recursively to any set of numbers. Thus the maximum will always be achieved by

```
int maxNum(int[] nums){
    int x = 0;

    for(int n : nums)
        if(n == 1)
            x += n;
        else
            if(x == 0)
                x = n;
            else
                x *= n;
    return x;
}
```

If the set of numbers is order.

Comment: He didn't make it explicit, but the problem allows the numbers to be negative.

Comment: Yeah, but that really is too simple to be mentioned: if(n<0){if(x<0){x*=n}else{x+=n}. This does have a little flaw, where the algorithm is trying to make the number always positive, but a higher x could be achieved by multiplying with two negatives, but I think the performance improvement is worth that. +1 for the nice idea

Comment: @Paul there is a little mistake btw: if(n==1) you should add one, not multiply...

Comment: @xXliolauXx oops, little typo. thanks, ill correct it

Comment: i dont think it can be that easy Paul..  with your solution, if i give u 1, 2, 2 u'll return 4 or may be 5  but right answer would be 6  (1+2)*2     btw do you see any issue with my solution?

Comment: @user3282540 the result of my code would be 5, which is the correct solution. 6 isn't correct result, since brackets aren't valid operators